# VB.Net Check if a website is open in IE

Tags: vb.net

I'm searching if it possible to check if some website for e.g. google.com is opened in IE. I have already this code but it was only for checking if IE is open and to close it, But it's not working.

```
Dim processCollection() As Process
processCollection = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore.exe")

If processCollection.Count > 0 Then
   For Each process As Process In processCollection
      process.Dispose()
   Next
   Return False
Else
   MessageBox.Show("Ie is now close", "IE")
End If
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please mark as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. Add Microsoft Internet Controls reference to project. It is available in COM. It will appear as SHDocVw

[image]

2. Now in property explorer of SHDocVw change Embedded InterOp types to false
   [image]
3. Save , Clean and Rebuild the project.
4. Import SHDocVw in your code.
5. Use below  piece of code

   ```
   For Each ie As InternetExplorer In New ShellWindows()
   Console.WriteLine(ie.LocationURL())
   Next
   ```

Comment: Now how can I specify eg. Google.com and if it open how can that write a msgbox. Sorry i never use console.writeline.

Comment: You can use string functions to find website in  ie.LocationURL.  This console. Writeline write output to console.  You can see the output in output window as well

Comment: I need to put the code into a timer but it not working.

Comment: A little problem if there is more than one website open only one website will be in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Function InternetExplorerRunning()
    For Each ie As InternetExplorer In New ShellWindows()
        Dim OpenWebsite As String
        OpenWebsite = ie
        If OpenWebsite = "google.com" Then
            MsgBox("Google is open")
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

This code is in a timer.

Comment: Please read my Solution with more depth. IE.LocationUrl() will give the URL. And then U can use like this OpenWebsite= ie.LocationUrl(); OpenWebsite.Contains("google.com")

Comment: WORKING Thanks !